# Rewrite with htaccess to pass argument to script

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

To start, I had a PHP script that I wanted to access as JSON since that matched the format of its output

Original:

```
/project/app/script.php
```

Updated:

```
/project/app/script.json
```

with this in *.htaccess* file:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^project/app/script.json$ /project/app/script.php [L]
```

So far so good. It works. Everyone (me) is happy. Time passes. And now I need to update it so that...

I would like to hit this URL structure:

```
/project/app/param/script.json
```

and have it mapped to:

```
/project/app/script.php?blah=param
```

It's been such a long day that I can't mentally do this. I can barely make myself a fresh coffee. Oh, an di need to keep the original rule intact.

Comment: Add `RewriteRule ^project/app/(\w+)/script.json$ /project/app/script.php?blah=$1 [L]`

Comment: Thank you! I was staring it this too long to make come up with that by myself. If you add this as the answer I'll mark it the Accepted answer.